# how to group by columnA and sum columnB, columnC in mixpanel JQL

Tags: mixpanel, jql

I have a JQL in mixpanel. I managed to get to a result in the following format:

```
key, count1, count2, count3
a  ,     10,      0,      0
a  ,      0,      3,      0
a  ,      0,      0,      7
b  ,      2,      0,      0
b  ,      0,      3,      0
b  ,      0,      0,      5
```

And I'd like to get the results like:

```
key, count1, count2, count3
a  ,     10,      3,      7
b  ,      2,      3,      5
```

In other words: groupBy(['key'], WHAT_REDUCER_DO_I_NEED???)

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple reducers in your groupBy statement like this

```
.groupBy(['key'], [
    mixpanel.reducer.sum('count1'),
    mixpanel.reducer.sum('count2'),
    mixpanel.reducer.sum('count3')
])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  .groupBy(["key"], function(accumulators, events){
    var sum = {"count1":0,"count2":0,"count3":0};
    for (var i = 0; i < accumulators.length; ++i) {
      sum["count1"] += accumulators[i]["count1"];
      sum["count2"] += accumulators[i]["count2"];
      sum["count3"] += accumulators[i]["count3"];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < events.length; ++i) {
      var event = events[i];
      sum["count1"] += event["count1"];
      sum["count2"] += event["count2"];
      sum["count3"] += event["count3"];
    }
    return sum;
  })
```